# CheckBox return true then the others CheckBox return false

Tags: c#, checkbox, boolean

I was wondering how to do that but I have 2 CheckBox in my DataGrid and I wanted to make that if one returns "true" then the other one has to automatically return "false",

```xml
<DataGrid Name="McDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding authors}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="813" Width="906" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,45,570,0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Produits" Binding="{Binding Produit}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Temporaire" Binding="{Binding Temporaire}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Jour" Binding="{Binding Jours}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Permanent" Binding="{Binding Permanent}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date D'installation" Binding="{Binding DateInstall}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="160" Header="Licence">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Height="25" DisplayMemberPath="Visu" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxLicence}" SelectedIndex="{Binding LicenceBox}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code SPIN" Binding="{Binding SPIN}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Please don't remove the question text. If you want to deleted your whole question you are welcome to, if you feel that's appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

It´s way easier to just use radiobuttons, its basically the same but it does the switching automatically.